# Ошибка при PUT-методе

Tags: java, spring, http

Пытаюсь сделать метод по обновлению сервиса. Но в ответ приходит `404` и вот такая ошибка `Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction`". Что это может быть?

метод Update ServiceService:

```
  public Service update(Service service) {
    Service serviceToUpdate = serviceRepository.findById(service.getId()).orElseThrow(() ->
        new RuntimeException("Requested entity was not found"));
    serviceToUpdate.setId(service.getId());
    serviceToUpdate.setName(service.getName());
    serviceToUpdate.setAddress(service.getAddress());
    serviceToUpdate.setLandmark(service.getLandmark());
    serviceToUpdate.setWeb(service.getWeb());
    serviceToUpdate.setPhone(service.getPhone());
    serviceToUpdate.setMinAge(service.getMinAge());
    serviceToUpdate.setMaxAge(service.getMaxAge());
    serviceToUpdate.setPhotoRaw(service.getPhotoRaw());
    serviceToUpdate.setCity(service.getCity());
    serviceToUpdate.setDistrict(service.getDistrict());
    serviceToUpdate.setMetroStation(service.getMetroStation());
    serviceToUpdate.setSeller(service.getSeller());
    return serviceRepository.save(serviceToUpdate);
  }
```

Контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/service/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  public ResponseEntity<String> updateService(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody Service
      service) {
    if (serviceService.findById(id) == null) {
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).build();
    } else {
      service.setId(id);
      serviceService.update(service);
      return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
  }
```

В ответ получаю такую ошибку:

```
{
    "status": "NOT_FOUND",
    "message": "Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction",
    "errors": [
        "Requested entity was not found"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Так вы сами эту ошибку и выбрасываете, если сущность по id не найдена. А по существу: выкладывайте весь стектрейс, а не верхушку

Comment: @Виктор Так в том-то и дело, что в базе этот id есть. Стектрейс чист, эта ошибка в постмане вылазит.

Comment: замените запрос на Optional и посмотрите что возвращает репозиторий. Если там null то ищите почему null